# Argument types from default value in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I declared a type "handler function" with one argument (for destructuring) and a function to add handlers

```js
type HandlerArg = any;
type MyHandler = (event?: HandlerArg) => any;

function AddHandler(handler: MyHandler) {}
```

But when I declare the arguments with default values, the type is infered as `any`

```js
AddHandler(({
  id = 1, // the type is "any"
}) => {
  console.log(id)
});

AddHandler(({
  children = [], // the type is "any"
}) => {
  console.log(children.length)
});
```

How I can set the types without make the next code?

```js
AddHandler(({
  id = 0,
  name = '',
}: { // this is very ugly
  id: number,
  name: string,
}) => {
  console.log(id);
  console.log(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The **design type** is *any* because this is how you declared your `MyHandler` and `HandlerArg` types - a function that expects an argument of type any.

Just because you set the default value of a particular handler instance to be a number or an array, doesn't change the type that the handler function expects.

You can create specific handlers that expect certain types and add them with `addHandler` (by the way, the convention in Javascript for function names is camelCased), for example:

```
const handlerWithNumber = (id: number = 1) => {
    console.log(id); // id is a number in Typescript
}

addHandler(handlerWithNumber);
```

So attempting to call `handlerWithNumber` with anything other than a number will raise a compile error in typescript.

```
handlerWithNumber(2); // Works.
handlerWithNumber("2"); // Error, Typescript won't compile this.
```

From your question, it is not clear what you intend to do with these handlers and why/how the type information of the handler arguments is important. But you need to understand that Typescript types only have meaning in Typescript in design time.

Typescript compiles your code to plain Javascript so all type information is lost in runtime and you are left with plain Javascript types. If you need to make any assertions regarding the types of the arguments in runtime, you need to use Javascript type checking techniques (`typeof`, `instanceof`, class names, checking null/undefined etc).

This also means that if your code used from plain Javascript, there is nothing stopping from calling this handler with any argument, regardless of your intended Typescript types, so write your code to expect that.

**UPDATE (in response to comment)**

You can also use generics to declare your handlers, the type will be inferred when adding the handler and the object type that can be passed to that handler will be solidified, like this:

```
type MyHandler<T> = (event?: T) => any;
function addHandler<T>(handler: MyHandler<T>) {
    //...
}

// This handler is a function that expects an object with single property
// id of type number (defaults to 1)
const handler = ({ id = 1}) => {
    console.log(id);
}

addHandler(handler);

handler({}); // id = 1
handler({id: 2}); // id = 2
handler({name: ""}); // Error
```

You can further restrict the interface of the passed object by using typescript [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, and yes i will use validations in runtime but the problem is the infered arguments of typescript, when i have to use types like classes there will be a lot coding problems :(

Comment: do you know if it possible infer the types if i put the handler directly, or you recommend me declare the function in other side and use it as argument in the `addHandler` calls?

Comment: I updated my answer to include an option with generics, which now looks like what you're after, based on your comment.